# Singleton method chaining in ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Is there a way to dinamically define and chain singleton methods in Ruby?

Say I have a class A with a method defined and an array constant. Something like this:

```
class A
  ARR = [:a, :b, :c, :d]

  class << self
    def test

    end
  end
end
```

Is there a way to dynamically define methods inside `test` so I end up with something like

```
A.test.a
A.test.b
...
```

Comment: `test` would have to return something that can have methods attached to it, like an object or class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

You could use an anonymous class:

```
class A
  ARR = [:a, :b, :c, :d]

  def self.test
    @test ||= Class.new {
      ARR.each do |method|
        define_method(method) { puts method }
      end
    }.new
  end    
end
```

Or you could use a private class:

```
class B
  ARR = [:a, :b, :c, :d]

  def self.test
    @test ||= Test.new
  end

  private

  class Test
    ARR.each do |method|
      define_method(method) { puts method }
    end
  end
end
```

In either case `A.test` will need to return some object from which you can call your `a`, `b`, `c`,  `d` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: don't do it. 
Build another class and use that from within test. 
If you really want to do it, you have to have something like a class or OpenStruct.

One way of hacking it is like this (beware this is not really efficient - it will build a class each time you call test):

```
class A
    ARR = [:a, :b, :c, :d]
    def self.test
        Class.new {
            ARR.each do |met|
                 define_method met do
                     puts met
                 end
            end
        }.new
    end    
end

A.test.a
A.test.b
```

Comment: why not do it? basically i want to have 'test' as a namespace for the other methods. I started wondering about this because i didn't want to use modules and was curious if it's doable.

Comment: the reason not to do it is that it's going to be hard and understand in the future. With a bit more work you can make clear what is going on. If there are going to be other people reading/maintaining this they are going to have a bad time